# Javascript find the nth element of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have looked at this code for a few hours and cannot understand how it works and how it gives an answer of 1.

If someone could explain this to me in easy to understand terms (I am new to Javascript) I would really appreciate it. The code is below. Thank you:

```
var array = [1, 3, 2, 9];
var one = -Infinity;
var two = -Infinity;
var three = -Infinity;

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

    if (array[i] > one) {
        three = two;
        two = one;
        one = array[i];
    }
}

console.log(three);
```

Comment: Try debugging the code, and placing a breakpoint inside the `for` loop, so you can see what values the variables take. It should help you understand.

Comment: Don't forget to declare `i`. Right now, that code falls prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). *(That's a post on my anemic little blog.)*

Comment: Just walk through the loop for yourself. At first, three = -∞, two= -∞, one = -∞, and i = 0. Then three = -∞, two = -∞, one = 1, and i =1. Then three = -∞, two = 1, one = 3, and i = 2...

Comment: Thank you for the fast and helpful replies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just think about the values in the loop and you will know why the last value of "three" is 1.
These are the values at the end of each iteration:

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|         i=0         |        i=1       |         i=2         |        i=3       |
|     three=-inf      |     three=-inf   |     three=-inf      |     three=1      | 
|     two=-inf        |     two=1        |     two=1           |     two=3        | 
|     one=1           |     one=3        |     one=3           |     one=9        | 
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
```